# Epplus not reading excel file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, epplus

Below is my code to read excel file.

Code.

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xls");
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;
ws.Cells["J12"].Value = "Test Write";
pck.Save();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xls");
```

When i run the code it throw a runtime error.

Error

```
System.Exception: Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password ---> System.IO.FileFormatException: File contains corrupted data.
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.FindPosition(Stream archiveStream)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOEndOfCentralDirectoryBlock.SeekableLoad(ZipIOBlockManager blockManager)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream archiveStream, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming, Boolean ownStream)
   at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipArchive.OpenOnStream(Stream stream, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage..ctor(Stream s, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Boolean streaming)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess, Boolean streaming)
   at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(Stream stream, FileMode packageMode, FileAccess packageAccess)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ConstructNewFile(Stream stream, String password)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.ConstructNewFile(Stream stream, String password)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage..ctor(FileInfo newFile)
   at Report.Form1.ExportToExcel1(DataTable Tbl, String ExcelFilePath) in C:\SMARTAG_PROJECT\SUREREACH\EXCEL\Report\Report\Form1.cs:line 39
```

Appreciated if anyone could advice/help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Epplus does not handle .xls (BIFF8 format) files as far as i know.

It handles the newer .xlsx (Open Office Xml) format.

You can use [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) though as it works for xls files.

Comment: Nice library. Not fast, but good not to worry about Com-foolery

Comment: Nice library, does it support both .xls and .xlsx? and another question is is it similar to `ExpertXls.ExcelLibrary`?

Comment: thanks man, was trying so hard to know why epplus is not opening excel, turns out it was xls

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert XLS to XLSX Format before reading the Excel sheet using EPPlus. You can find more information in [**this**](https://medium.com/@lockevn/convert-excel-format-xls-to-xlsx-using-c-3e1a348fca22) post.

Answer (score 0):

In the date of this post EPPLUS (v4.4.1) seems to handle xls files just like it does with xlsx:

Here is an example:

```
  using (var target = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\target.xls")))
        {
            target.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");
            target.Workbook.Worksheets.Last().Cells["A1:A12"].Value = "Hi";
            target.Save();
        }
```

also tested your code:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xls");
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
ws.View.ShowGridLines = false;
ws.Cells["J12"].Value = "Test Write";
pck.Save();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Excel\\SampleStockTakeExceptionReport.xls");
```

and it works without any issues.

Comment: The resulting file is still in OpenXML Format, just with a different fileextension. Excel will tell you when the file is opened. Also the GitHub page also does not mention any xls support.